# ASP.net MVC bootstrap dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've been following this video [Create Project & Setup for Responsive Design using Bootstrap](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQIRBhP3rho) and applied what do literally but found a problem in the bootstrap library, which is that Dropdownlist not do dropdown!! which conains 2 items... I think the problem is in `JavaScript`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @* Header Menu *@

        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header"><h1>My first MVC Web Site</h1> </a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-main">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="/" style="text-shadow: 0.08em 0.08em 0.3em #ffd800"><h4> Home</h4> </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false" style="text-shadow: 0.08em 0.08em 0.3em #ffd800"><h4>Items </h4><span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="/Campaign"><strong> Item1</strong></a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/Room"><strong>Item2</strong></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            @* Page Header *@
            <div class="page-header" id="banner">

            </div>

            @* Page Body *@
            <div class="page-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        @RenderBody()
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>


    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: dropdownlist not working]

Comment: @albrg need COde not Images

Comment: Code in video ... I will put it

Comment: Obviously, you lost a close tag for <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

Comment: I put the end tag but the problem not solved !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you are missing a `</ul>` closing tag for `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">`.

You also have a trailing `</a>` that does not close anything after `<h1>My first MVC Web Site</h1>.`

If you are using the MVC visual studio template. The bootstrap.min.js file is actually located at ~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js and not ~/Scripts/bootstrap/boostrap.min.js. So you script tag at the bottom should be `<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Instead of the manual script tag you can also try one of the below options:
`@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")` - Include in MVC bund config, includes both bootstrap.js and respond.js

CDN link for bootstrap js:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: thanks, I put the tags but the problem still exists ..
for the bootstrap.min.js file I created folder in Scripts folder and I put the files in it just lie the video do.

Answer (score 0):

Although i couldn't go through the video, i believe this cshtml file is a layout page.
the logic for the drop down should be in the view i.e the view called by `@RenderBody()`

You can as well store the list items in the controller using ViewBag
eg.

Your Controller

```
public ActionResult Dropdown()
{
     ViewBag.Myitems = List<Foo>();
     return View();
}
```

In your view

```
...
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
   @Html.DropDownList("Myitems", null, "Select Items", new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
...
```

#### Note:

`Viewbag.Myitems` Must match the name in the view else it will throw an error as it could not find the key specified.

This assumes that you are developing with Asp.Net MVC 5

Comment: no I am developing  with Asp.Net MVC 4 ..., yes this code is Layout but the problem still exist